# Cannot start virtualbox 5

Tags: virtualbox

I am on Ubuntu 15.04 using kernel 3.19.0-28-generic. Cannot start virtual-box 5, I throws this error:

[image: Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component: MachineWrap Interface: IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}]

I am getting same error with other VMs (fedora, windows xp) too

Log for Debian VM is [here](http://sprunge.us/SgRj)

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling VirtualBox?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda yes

Comment: Please try this `sudo chmod o-w /usr `.

Comment: @A.B. you giving me very powerful command, are you sure? also why it has to do with `other` users' writer permission?

Comment: Per default, `others` have no write permissions in `/usr` therefore no risk. And I found this hint in a German Ubuntu Wiki: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/VirtualBox/Problembehebung

Comment: @A.B. there is not writer permission for `others` on `/usr` already -_-

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29588/discussion-between-a-b-and-edward-torvalds).

Comment: Come in the general chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room @cl-netbox is waiting

Comment: There should some logs files in '~/VIrtualBoxs VM/debian/Logs' or something like that in your machine. Can you please post them?.

Comment: @JavierRivera 
Log for Debian VM is [here](http://sprunge.us/SgRj)

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=41695#p187648) on VirtualBox Forums: "Opening the *.vbox file and removing the GuestPropert for VersionEx resolves the problem each time.".

Comment: @Cornelius how do I remove GuestPropert for VersionEx? also how to open *.vbox file?

Comment: .vbox file is XML and can be edited with text editor.

Comment: @Cornelius what to edit actually?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I've just installed the latest Ubuntu update, and VirtualBox stopped working after restart. I was working with one VM before restart. I'll re-install VirtualBox4.

Comment: @GUIJunkie thanks for your help, so now I have installed virtualbox v4 and it works fine, maybe there is a bug in v5

Comment: Same thing here. Installed 4.3 and works like a charm. I had problems with the screen settings in 5.0, so this is better. Buggy v5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like version 5.0 isn't ready for Ubuntu 15.04. I've had some problems. Reinstalling the last stable version (4.3) solved it.

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-5.0
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3
```